# Using localstorage with componentDidMount in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(this.ApiURL + '/tv/dailyTV?location=' + localStorage.getItem('location'))
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
              this.setState({
                companyname : data.static.companyname,
                companymission : data.static.companymission,
                videocount : data.static.videocount,
                companyasset : data.static.companyasset
              })
            })
  }
```

I want to fetch a data in my react application using a data from local storage. But component render before localstorage read the value so localStorage.getItem('location') return null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 this.state = {
          location : localStorage.getItem('location')
        };
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(this.ApiURL + '/tv/dailyTV?location=' + this.state.location)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async componentDidMount() {
const loc = await localStorage.getItem('location')
    fetch(this.ApiURL + '/tv/dailyTV?location=' + loc)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
              this.setState({
                companyname : data.static.companyname,
                companymission : data.static.companymission,
                videocount : data.static.videocount,
                companyasset : data.static.companyasset
              })
            })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`async-wait`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to achieve your goal.

Try:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const location = await localStorage.getItem('location')

    if(location) {
       fetch(this.ApiURL + '/tv/dailyTV?location=' + location)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
              this.setState({
                companyname : data.static.companyname,
                companymission : data.static.companymission,
                videocount : data.static.videocount,
                companyasset : data.static.companyasset
              })
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before each and every Component gets render declare a state variable...

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    location: true
  };
}
componentDidMount() {
    const location = localStorage.getItem('location');
    fetch(this.ApiURL + '/tv/dailyTV?location=' + location)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({
                companyname : data.static.companyname,
                companymission : data.static.companymission,
                videocount : data.static.videocount,
                companyasset : data.static.companyasset
              })
            })

}
```